# Adding a attachment (jpg) to this PHP mail Script

Tags: php, email, jpeg, attachment, send

I was trying to add a code, that allows me to send a attachment (jpg) over php!

My current script:

```
<?php
$input = array("@[XXXX:0]", "@[XXXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]",                 "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]", "@[XXX:0]");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]];
?>

<?php
 $to = "XXX@XXX.com";
 $subject = "Wuensche euch allen ein schoenes Wochenende.
Sehn uns hier: @[XXXXXXXXXXXX:0]!
Shouts heute gehen an ". $input[$rand_keys[0]]." <3.
Kuss, XXX.";
 $body = "bacon";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message to Facebook successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message to Facebook failed!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

So something like:

```
$file = picture.jpg
```

(which is in the same directory!)

If that works:

could we do something like

```
$file = $random_picture
```

and

```
$random_picture = 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg etc.
```

So that the script pics up a random number.jpg and sends it everytime i load it?

Thank you! :)

Comment: You can get help at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#113161

Comment: Yeah, but im not very good in PHP. I tried it, but i dont know excatly where to add it to the correct lines :(

Answer (score 1):

You can get help form [HTML EMAIL WITH JPEG ATTACHMENTS TUTORIAL](http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/mail2.htm).

And you need to change a little bit in your body part like this:

```
$pics = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg');
//Pick key of the random image
$random_key = array_rand($pics,1);

$file = file_get_contents("YOUR_ABSOLUTE_URL".$pics[$random_key]);

$body.= "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"".$pics[$random_key]."\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"".$pics[$random_key]."\"\r\n"
."\r\n"
.chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
```

And you send the email as you are sending now.

NOTE:

Have look at [array_rand](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

EDIT:

Full Code is as follows:

```
<?php
$to = "XXX@XXX.com";
$subject = "YOUR_SUBJECT";
$body = "bacon";
$pics = array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg');
//Pick key of the random image
$random_key = array_rand($pics,1);

$file = file_get_contents($pics[$random_key]);

$body.= "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"".$pics[$random_key]."\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"".$pics[$random_key]."\"\r\n"
."\r\n"
.chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    echo("<p>Message to Facebook successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
    echo("<p>Message to Facebook failed!</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Can someone post the full script with included new attachment scripts?
It would help me a very lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something like below would do I guess (without testing);

```
$randomPicArr = array('a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg','e.jpg');
$randomNum = rand(0,5);
$random_picture = $randomPicArr[$randomNum];
```

Comment: That looks great! But im absolutley a php noob.
I dont know where the to put the relevant codes into the script :(